# HQL compare times without date

Tags: hibernate, hql

Hello i need to get data from postgres postgres DB table using HQL query like this

```
SELECT F.flightType, F.obDepartAirport, F.obArriveAirport, F.obDepartDate, F.obArriveDate, F.obFlightNumber, F.ibDepartAirport, F.ibArriveAirport, F.ibDepartDate, F.ibArriveDate, F.ibFlightNumber, F.seatsAvailable, F.id, F.createdAt, F.adultPrice, F.childPrice, F.infantPrice, F.nights, F.supplierCode, F.currency, F.additionalUIDInfo, F.obCabinType, F.ibCabinType
FROM ScannedFlight as F
WHERE
F.obDepartDate >= :fromDateStart AND F.obDepartDate < :fromDateEnd AND F.flightType = :flightType AND F.obDepartAirport IN (:fromAirports) AND F.obArriveAirport IN (:toAirports) AND F.supplierCode in (:operatorCodes) AND F.nights = :nights AND ( CAST (F.obDepartDate AS time) between time :obDepartTimeStart and time :obDepartTimeEnd)
ORDER BY F.adultPrice
```

The problem in section `( CAST (F.obDepartAirport AS time) between time :obDepartTimeStart and time :obDepartTimeEnd)` hibernate  dont know postgres function time. My question how to extract only time and compare it.

Comment: Why dont you write select F from ScannedFlight as F where..... I guess you are writing your all projections in above query.

Comment: Nope only part and there is query generator which has same "select" part and different from and where. But it is not the case of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it using cast

```
( CAST (F.obDepartDate AS time) between CAST(:obDepartTimeStart AS time) and CAST(:obDepartTimeEnd AS time))
```